# Omniauth and Devise started to fail out of the blue, this morning, when authenticating with Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, facebook-login, omniauth

Everything was fine and then:

```
I, [2017-03-28T02:54:18.998055 #663]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 14.3ms | ActiveRecord: 8.5ms)
I, [2017-03-28T02:54:26.225944 #663]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 176.109.217.212 at 2017-03-28 02:54:26 -0400
I, [2017-03-28T02:54:26.411915 #663]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=CODE and STATE" for 176.109.217.212 at 2017-03-28 02:54:26 -0400
I, [2017-03-28T02:54:26.566419 #663]  INFO -- : Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
I, [2017-03-28T02:54:26.566667 #663]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"code"=>"CODE", "state"=>"STATE"}
I, [2017-03-28T02:54:26.567608 #663]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://example.com/users/sign_in
```

All Facebook logins seem to be down, however the error is hard to catch. I display login failed "credentials invalid" to my users but it's not their fault. How can I tell them facebook's to blame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook made a migration yesterday during the night. You have to use a version of `omniauth-facebook` >= 4.0.0 to make it work again (source https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/278)

Update your Gemfile with `gem 'omniauth-facebook', '4.0.0'`, then run `bundle update` and everything should go back to normal.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Done, gem upgraded fine, deployed and everything is up to date there too, But having the same issue still. Having the same issue, I was on version 2.0.1 since last year.

Comment: Did you verify on Facebook (in your app settings) under the Facebook Login section that you have a redirect URI? 
In my case this was set to blank after their migration.

Comment: Managed to fix it. Restarted the server, apparently the upgrade triggered some upgrades in the dependencies and a reboot was necessary.

Comment: Try this. Don't use 'bundle update' - it's updated all gems and kill your app. 
[How to fix invalid credential? omniauth-facebook gem broken after Facebook API Deprecation.](https://mozpi.com/articles/how-to-fix-invalid-credential-omniauth-facebook-gem-broken-after-facebook-api-deprecation-id-83)

Comment: @n1ck you're right it updates all the gems *for wich you didn't specify a version*. That's why you should always follow theses rules when adding a gem in your Gemfile : 
Use a versionless Gemfile declarations for gems that are safe to update often, such as pg, thin, and debugger.
Use an exact version in the Gemfile for fragile gems, such as Rails.